# ConstraintLayout by percentage is overlapping

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

So I was learning android programming. I'm trying to make an app that reads all files and shows it in a list. So I was making the list item layout, at first I used Linear Layout using weights but android studio suggested that nested weights are not good. So after some searching I learned that the better alternative was Constraint Layout. So I tried making it using constraint layout as such

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_imageview"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filename_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="File Name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail_imageview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filesize_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="File Size"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filename_textview"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail_imageview"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filetype_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="File Type"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filename_textview"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/filesize_textview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The issue is that the filesize and filetype are given percent 50% each but they are overlapping and overflowing. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the value of `layout_constraintWidth_percent` (as well as height) is based on the **parent container** width - however left of your items is a thumbnail `thumbnail_imageview` that occupies space. So there's less than 100% horizontal space left for two widgets with 50 percent width, respectively.

To fix it, wrap your two items in a container (eg another `ConstraintLayout`) and align that container to the right of the thumbnail.

Comment: I placed the text boxes in another Constraint view after the Image View as you suggested and it worked.